# Perl multiline match for 'something' which starts without '#\s'

Tags: grep, regular-expression, perl

UPDATE:

1. The REAL answer to this MULTILINE question was given here by Stephane https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/521560/354415
2. Alternatively go line by line with perl by Terdon below: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/521512/354415
3. Alternatively go line by line with IFS by myself here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/521550/354415

**Here is my new toy:**

Problem is that I want it to match only on lines which do not have the #\s* in front of the parameter.

Please do not provide alternative code e.g. sed etc. use perl

```
perl -we 'my $file= "parameter=9
# parameter=10
parameter=10
"; $file=~ s/.*((?<!^# ))parameter\s*=.*/parameter=replaced/g; print(":$file:\n")'
```

Expected output

```
parameter=replaced
# parameter=10
parameter=replaced
```

PS if you are interested to see how I progressed with this, look here:[Perl Negative Lookbehind with variable length bypass maybe?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/521523/perl-negative-lookbehind-with-variable-length-bypass-maybe/521550#521550)

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: root@ns1:~# ./test.sh

   parameter=replaced
# parameter=10
parameter=replaced

Comment: Basically it should not replace the second parameter which has a hash and space in front.

Comment: "Please do not provide alternative code." Why not? Your code is not very clear or efficient. For example, you are creating 3 useless variables instead of using the existing `$ARGV[N]` ones and you have needless parentheses around your `print` call.

Comment: Its only for readability.. You are free to modify, but keep the original idea intact. i.e. INPUT VARS > perl > OUTPUT VAR. Thank you.  What I meant by altrnatives is about solutions in other languages and methods. This has to be kept inline with a project that requires perl regex

Comment: I modified the code to make it simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is complicated by your choice to pass the multi-line string as a single variable. it is much easier to just convert that to an array so you can use the `s///` operator in its simplest form. Try this:
You said you're not interested in code improvements, but to help future users, here's a simplified version of what you wrote which also avoids the bad practice of using ALLCAPS for non-environment variables:

```
newparameter='parameter=replaced'
filesection='
   parameter=9
# parameter=10
parameter=10
'

matchparamperl='^([^#]*)parameter\s*=.*'

sectionfixed=$( perl -le '
                         @lines=split(/\n/,$ARGV[0]);
                         s/$ARGV[1]/$1$ARGV[2]/g for @lines; 
                         print join "\n", @lines
                         ' "$filesection" "$matchparamperl" "$newparameter") 
echo "$sectionfixed"
```

That will return:

```
$ echo "$sectionfixed"

   parameter=replaced
# parameter=10
parameter=replaced
```

Alternatively, a little shorter:

```
sectionfixed=$( perl -le '
                         do{
                            s/$ARGV[1]/$1$ARGV[2]/g; print
                         } for split(/\n/,$ARGV[0])
                         ' "$filesection" "$matchparamperl" "$newparameter")
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time.  Your answer is better than mine, because yours allows for any number of spaces and any number of # before the parameter to be disregarded. However, as you rightly mention, it is NOT using the multiline string and has to go line by line. My question was for multiline in order to investigate solutions. I would like to invite you then to something more relevant here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/521523/perl-negative-lookbehind-with-variable-length-bypass-maybe?noredirect=1#comment963984_521523 where this answer is more appropriate.

Comment: @conanDrum you can do it with a multiline string but that's just making your life harder and your code less clear for no good reason.

Comment: I agree, but this was the point of the question. to see what can be done with multiline. And this answers it. nothing much in the way of what was requested. It has to be done line by line. Having said that, the only answer that answered the question regarding multiline was Negative Lookbehind, i think you will aggree.

Comment: I already mentioned you in the other thread. unfortunately I cannot upvote anything yet.

Comment: with your script, when it is done with the loop, how can I return some variable showing how many substitutions were made? or at least if any were made.

Comment: @conanDrum that's a completely different issue. And it will depend on how you want this information to be shown. Please post a separate question if you need help with that. But here's a starter: `sectionfixed=$( perl -le '@lines=split(/\n/,$ARGV[0]); $k+=s/$ARGV[1]/$1$ARGV[2]/g for @lines; print join "\n", @lines; print STDERR "$k substitutions made\n";' "$filesection" "$matchparamperl" "$newparameter")`. Of course, it doesn't make much sense if you insist on mixing perl and the shell as you have requested.

Comment: here it is: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/521615/354415 please take a look if you can. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
contents='
   parameter=9
# parameter=10
parameter=10
'

sed '/^#/!s/parameter[[:blank:]]*=.*/parameter=replaced/' <<<"$contents"
```

Output:

```
   parameter=replaced
# parameter=10
parameter=replaced
```

The `sed` code is simply applying the substitution to all lines not starting with a `#` character.

Comment: No thanks.. The task has to be done with the code provided. Only the regex must be manipulated.

Comment: @conanDrum then please edit your question and make that clear so we don't waste your time, or ours, with solutions that won't work for you. And why can't we fix your perl code? There are a few odd choices you've made there and the syntax is more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: Not true... Only the first parameter is changed with MATCHPARAMPERL='^[^#].*parameter\s*=.*'. this is because  you placed the ^ at the start and this caused it to replace only the first one.

Comment: @conanDrum I know, that's why I removed that bit. You may want to look up "negative lookbehind assertions".

Comment: can you provide a link to an example on a similar situation

Comment: I am trying your suggestion. Look at my new example. Still it eludes me. But now I think I got it )))

Comment: Why `$(sed...)` just to print it? Unless you are demonstrating capturing the return value...

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I was following the code in the question, which keeps everything in variables.  At least it did when I answered it.

Comment: @ Kusalananda actually negative lookahead is what fixed it in the end!! look here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/521523/perl-negative-lookbehind-with-variable-length-bypass-maybe/521550#521550

Comment: @conanDrum I know. I provided a `sed` solution to make the code readable. If you're using special PCRE patterns, it will be a mystery to future you what the code does in a couple of year's time :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -we 'my $file= "parameter=9
# parameter=10
parameter=10
"; $file=~ s/.*((?<!# ))parameter\s*=.*/parameter=replaced/g; print(":$file:\n")'
```

This is how its done )))

Output:

```
parameter=replaced
# parameter=10
parameter=replaced
```

Called Negative Lookbehind
http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/RegexLookahead.aspx

**Thanks to  Kusalananda for providing the idea.**

I would never have thought of it.

Comment: That isn't the output you asked for. The empty line and the leading space from the first line have been removed. And yu have ignored your own requirement to go `INPUT VARS > perl > OUTPUT VAR`.

Comment: based on -2 points on the question, and your own complaint, I decided to make things simpler. So now the point is this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/521523/perl-negative-lookbehind-with-variable-length-bypass-maybe maybe you can help?

Comment: And yes, when I simplified the code, I forgot to change the expected output )) I will do it now.